# Android Browser - 'Next/Prev' form buttons on Soft Keyboard do not work in iFrame

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, iframe, browser

I do not have code examples for this one and am curious if this is a known browser bug as I've been unable to Google my way out of this one.

Testing on a **Samsung Galaxy S4**, using the native browser, I am unable to use the '**Next/Prev**' form helper buttons (on the Soft Keyboard - NOT for browser history) when going through inputs on a form.  *This form is inside an iFrame*.

I see a lot of tickets related to PhoneGap.  I am not using PhoneGap and is simply a webpage with the form inside an iFrame.

Two questions.

1. Is this a known browser bug and is there a workaround?
2. Can I listen for an event on those buttons and create a custom next/prev functionality?

**Thanks!**